# Optimal way to reshape dataframe in R to have observation on columns

Tags: r, reshape

Given e.g. the Orange data set, I would like to arrange the observations in a matrix in which the measurements (circumference) taken on each tree are arranged in rows (for a total of 5 rows).

One unsatisfactory way of obtaining this result is as follows:

```
mat<-matrix(Orange[,3],nrow=5, ncol = 7,byrow=T, dimnames = list(c(unique(Orange$Tree)),c(1:7)))
```

Comment: This might be of your interest: [How to reshape data from long to wide format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way would be using the `dcast( )` function within the `data.table` package.
This allows you to convert data from long to wide. In this case, I've created an ID to could the number of records per `Tree`.

In the re-shaped data, `Tree` becomes our primary column and `circumference` is recorded in 7 unique columns (one for each `age`).

```
library(data.table)

Orange <- data.table(Orange)[,ID := seq(1:.N), by=Tree]

Orange2 <- dcast(
  data = Orange,
  formula = Tree ~ ID,
  value.var = "circumference")

Orange2

  Tree  1  2   3   4   5   6   7
1:    3 30 51  75 108 115 139 140
2:    1 30 58  87 115 120 142 145
3:    5 30 49  81 125 142 174 177
4:    2 33 69 111 156 172 203 203
5:    4 32 62 112 167 179 209 214
```

**EDIT** (in response to additional comments/questions):
Technically the data is already ordered by `Tree` (defined within the data). This is because the variable `Tree` is a factor variable with preset levels. To order numerically, here are 2 things: (1) Order by `as.character( )` and (2) Re-level the variable.

```
Orange2[order(as.character(Tree),]
1:    1 30 58  87 115 120 142 145
2:    2 33 69 111 156 172 203 203
3:    3 30 51  75 108 115 139 140
4:    4 32 62 112 167 179 209 214
5:    5 30 49  81 125 142 174 177

class(Orange$Tree)
[1] "ordered" "factor"

levels(Orange$Tree)
[1] "3" "1" "5" "2" "4"

Orange2[,Tree := factor(Tree, c("1","2","3","4","5"), ordered = FALSE)]

Orange2[order(Tree),]
   Tree  1  2   3   4   5   6   7
1:    1 30 58  87 115 120 142 145
2:    2 33 69 111 156 172 203 203
3:    3 30 51  75 108 115 139 140
4:    4 32 62 112 167 179 209 214
5:    5 30 49  81 125 142 174 177
```

Comment: Thanks this certainly works. I was wandering if there was a way to 1) obtain the same outcome with base-R (but without loops) and 2) have rows sorted according to Tree number

Comment: @mimmo970, It's likely this could be done in base R using the `reshape( )` function, but I am less familiar with that function. Are you not able to access the `data.table` package? Also, I edited the answer above to provide insight into your question on sorting the data.

Answer (score 0):

In `base`, you could simply do:

```r
aggregate(circumference ~ Tree, Orange, I)
```

If you don't want to order it afterwards: `aggregate(circumference ~ as.character(Tree), Orange, I)` (that will strip the factor ordering).

Or similar to @RyanF:

```r
Orange$id <- sequence(rle(as.character(Orange$Tree))$lengths)

reshape(Orange[,-2],
        idvar = "Tree",
        timevar = "id",
        direction = "wide")
```

Output:

```
   Tree circumference.1 circumference.2 circumference.3 circumference.4 circumference.5 circumference.6 circumference.7
1     1              30              58              87             115             120             142             145
8     2              33              69             111             156             172             203             203
15    3              30              51              75             108             115             139             140
22    4              32              62             112             167             179             209             214
29    5              30              49              81             125             142             174             177
```